# Not able to initialise the object In Python

Tags: python

Getting error while trying to initialise an object of sub class. Can you help me to fix this error.

base class

```
 class B(object):
    def __init__(self, builder):
        self.test = builder.test
    #using builder pattern here
    class Builder:
        test = None

        @classmethod
        def set_test(cls, value):
            cls.test = value
            return cls


        @classmethod
        def build(cls):
            return B(cls)


#main class       
class A(B):
  def __init__(self):
      super(A, self).__init__()


Obj = A(B.Builder.set_test("dummy").build())
```

Error: TypeError: new() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Are you sure it would even parse as pasted? Class isn't supposed to be upper case.

Comment: Don't you need to actually give set_test() a value?

Comment: Sorry. in actual code it takes default value too.

Comment: @KenKinder I have not pasted it, I had typed this complete code here. There was some issue while pasting the original code

Comment: Add function call and function definition to the description.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling this:

```
Obj = A(B.Builder.set_test("dummy").build())
                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

`.build()` is being called on the output of set_test(). set_test() returns `None`. For me, running this code, I'm seeing this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 23, in <module>
    Obj = A(B.Builder.set_test("dummy").build())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build'
```

Comment: Could you please explain it little more. I am not able to catch this properly. I tried this code in __new__ of child class, still failing with same error.

Comment: `__init__` is the constructor. I think it might really help if you more or less started with a good primer on Python classes and methods. It's a big much to go over here.

Comment: Sorry, it was there by mistake. Now I have corrected that part.

Comment: Could you please look one more time

Comment: @Abhay Ok, I looked at your updated code and I see a problem, but it's not the error you're getting.

Comment: It supposed to be return 'cls' itself. I think it is last typo error.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, builder):
        self.test = builder.test
    #using builder pattern here
    class Builder:
        test = None

        @classmethod
        def set_test(cls,value):
            cls.test = value
            return cls


        @classmethod
        def build(cls):
            return B(cls)


#main class
class A(B):
  def __init__(self,B):
      super(A, self).__init__(B)


Obj = A(B.Builder.set_test("dummy").build())
```

this code is working for me :)

Comment: @Thanks a lot. It worked for me too. Could you please suggest what is this trick? What concept I was missing.

Comment: Jainil, I would like to know,  in case of multiple inheritance, do I need to pass all parent class names in constructor?

Comment: try using pycharm, it suggests the function's required parameter, when you use a function. You were missing some parameters, but I forgot your code :) I think some init parameters were missing.

Comment: even you removed your previous code. remember in python you have to look others Code initially to learn it. the book knowledege don't work . so better to copy as many codes, run them and read them and analyse outputs.

Comment: I don't know the concept names or concept. concept can't be explained , they changes person to person or say version to version. and about the trick, there is no trick , just one trick copy as many code as you can and run them.